# Return the opportunities without a contact role?

Tags: soql

I want to return the opportunities without contact roles, and this query doesn't seem to do the trick. Any suggestions?

```
select  count(contactid), opportunity.name
from opportunityContactRole

 group by opportunity.name
 having count(contactid) = null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select Id
from Opportunity
where Id not in (
    select OpportunityId
    from OpportunityContactRole
    )
```